Number of solutions to $x+y+z=6$, where $x,y,z \in [0,5] \cap \mathbb{Z}$ and are distinct
My method:
Given that $x,y,z$ are distinct.
Let $x<y<z$, $a = x$, $b = y-x$, and $c = z-y$.
So the question transforms into finding $a,b,c$ such that $3a+2b+c = 14$, $a,b,c \in [0,5]\cap\mathbb{Z}$.
This is equal to coefficient of $t^6$ in
$(t^0 +t^3+t^6\ldots)(t^0+t^2+t^4+t^6\ldots)(t^0+t+t^2+t^3+t^4+t^5+t^6)$
(neglecting higher powers)
$= (1+t+2t^2 + 3t^3 + 4t^4 + 5t^5+ 6t^6\ldots)$
$= 6$
So, there are $6$ solutions where $x, y, z$ are distinct. We rearrange and get $6\cdot3! = 36$ solutions.
But, if I count cases manually, then I am getting $18$ distinct solutions, which are $(0,1,5)$, $(0,2,4)$ and $(1,2,3)$. Since I may permute each triple, there are $3\cdot3!=18$ solutions in this case.
Where did I go wrong?

distinct solutions and $x,y,z$ distinct is something different, you mean the latter one right?

@VincentBatens Yes thats what i mean

According to your definitions of $a,b,c$,  $3a + 2b + c$ is equal to 6.

@snow yes it is

What was the reason to use $a,b,c$ instead of $x,y,z$?

Where does $3a+2b+c=14$ come from? Why do you say you got $9$ distinct solutions then show a calculation that gives $18$? Since $x$, $y$, $z$ are distinct, are you sure $b$ and $c$ could be zero? (This last bit is where you've gone wrong, by the way)

@ChrisLewis yes it was a typo i meant 18 only. as for the 3a+2b+c part its a method we learnt . you can try it out with some numbers

and if its wrong, could you give a general method for number of solutions of x+y+z = n where xyz are distinct and xyz belongs to [something to something]

$b,c \in [1,5]$ not $[0,5].$  That is if any of them are 0 then x,y,z are not distinct.

Please read your question again. You've said $3a+2b+c=14$, and two people have already pointed this out to you. This method will with, but if you allow $b=0$, then you will get solutions where $x=y$.

@user317176 no, you can have $a=x=0$. But neither $b$ nor $c$ can be zero because these ensure $x$, $y$ and $z$ are distinct.

@ChrisLewis after taking a = 0 but b and c belongs only to 1,5 im getting the coefficient as 3. what are those 3 cases im getting? is it  (015) (0 2 4) and (123)?

Why is most of the mathematics in this not properly formatted (use MathJax!) when the little part in the middle talking this as the coefficient of $t^6$ is?

@Mathslover it would really help if you took extra time to check what you've written. Not only do you still have the typo that's been pointed out to you in the question, you clearly do not have $a=0$ but (I'm guessing) $a\in [0,5]$. You can work out the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ and from those the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$. The main point is to understand why this method works and why it's useful - you wouldn't want to work out these sums for a total of, say, $100$ by hand.

"is it (015) (0 2 4) and (123)?" - yes.

@ChrisLewis yes i think i got my mistakes and the method properly. thanks a lot!

The correct equations are
$$
3a+2b+c=6; a\in [0,5], b,c, \in [1,5]
$$
which is the $[t^6](1+t^3+t^6+t^9+\cdots)(t^2+t^4+t^6\cdots)(t+t^2+t^3+t^4+t^5+t^6+\cdots)=3t^6$
corresponding to the 3 solutions $(a,b,c)=(0,1,4), (0,2,2)$ and $(1,1,1)$ corresponding to the ordered $(x,y,z)=(0,1,5), (0,2,4), (1,2,3)$.
This is the same as reading the 6th value (=3) from https://oeis.org/A069905 , see the Comment of Walsh there.

$x+y+z = 6$ and x,y,z are distinct integers
Let $x<y<z$ and $a = x, b = y-x, c = z-y$
$3a+2b+c = 6, a \ge 0$ and $b,c \ge 1$
This is equal to coefficient of $t^6$ in
$(t^0 + t^3+t^6+\cdots)(t^2+t^4+t^6+\cdots)(t+t^2+t^3+t^4+t^5+t^6 + \cdots)$
$t^3 + t^4 + 2t^5 + 3t^6 + \cdots$
There are 3 ways for $3a+2b+c = 6$
Specifically $(a,b,c) = (0,1,4) \text { or }(0,2,2) \text { or } (1,1,1)$
Which correspond to $(x,y,z) = (0,1,5), (0,2,4)\text { or } (1,2,3)$ respectively
There are 3 ways for $x+y+z = 6$ with $x<y<z$
And then you can permute
